# Невозможность построить план запроса и выполнить его

Tags: sql, sql-server, анализ-плана-запроса

Столкнулся с проблемой, при которой оптимизатор не может построить план запроса. Не актуальный, не ожидаемый. Соответственно запрос не выполняется (не ждал более 3 часов). Блокировок никаких нет, но это ожидаемо. Их не может быть они возникают на этапе выполнения.
Статистика в порядке, более того, создавал даже руками специально фильтрованную под запрос. Объекты целые (DBCC без ошибок). Основная часть данных тянется и секционированной таблицы, по дням, функция работает корректно.
ver. MS SQL 2016 SP2 CU 17

Подскажите куда копать? С чем может быть связано подобное поведение?

Comment: А что с ожиданиями для сессии в которой выполняется запрос? sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats для этой сессии. Попробуйте поиграться с версией CE на запросе `OPTION( USE HINT ('FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION') )`

Comment: _"не может построить план запроса"_ т.е. ошибка 8622, или что?

Comment: @i-one нет никаких ошибок, не строит и все. Как будто сессия виснет.

Comment: А-а, т.е. следует читать _"ждал более 3 часов"_ (просто написано _**не** ждал_). Тогда, действительно, первым делом смотреть ожидания в сессии.